# What are the differences between Von Neuman's definition of natural numbers and Zermelo's?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, set-theory

I know that they both define the natural numbers. But is one better than other? Does one have a week point or runs into problem? If so what is it?

Comment: What's Zermelo's definition?

Comment: @GitGud I presume the one with $s(n)=\{n\}$.

Comment: If by Zermelo's definition you mean $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\},...$, then it can hardly be generalized to infinite ordinals.

Comment: @Max Yes that is what I mean. Would you please elaborate further on what you mean by "can hardly be generalized to infinite ordinals"?

Comment: @K.Smith : as Noah Schweber mentions under his answer, try it yourself : what should $\omega$ be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the most important point is that only one of them generalizes beyond the naturals. Less importantly, but still worth observing, is the fact that "$<$" is much easier to define for the von Neumann ordinals (it's just "$\in$"), and similarly for the other basic operations/relations on natural numbers and general well-orderings. *(Note that this second point still applies even if you don't care about infinite ordinals.)*

Comment: You mean Zermelo's definition can not be used to define numbers beyond naturals?

Comment: @K.Smith Yes, that is what I mean. Try it yourself: what should the "Zermelo-version" of $\omega$ be?

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks.

Comment: Like you said in your other answer {{{...}}} is not possible due to "axiom of foundation". The how can this encoding even be used to represent the natural numbers, because it can not represent infinity? Or maybe I am missing something in the definition of natural numbers!